# Why can't I convert bytestring with length == 1 to char?

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I have the following code snippet in rlp.py:

```
def encode(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        if len(obj) == 1 and chr(obj) < 128: 
            return obj
```

Why dosen't this work?

```
import rlp as r
r.encode('\x0f')
```

Gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    if len(obj) == 1 and chr(obj) < 128: 
    TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

And I don't get the difference between b'\x0f' and '\x0f' and b'\xf' and '\xf'

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doesn't chr() return a string? In that case you'd be comparing a string with an integer in `chr(obj) < 128` which would explain the error message.

Comment: chr("h") gives me the same error. So I guess thats not the case.

Comment: If you want to get the integer unicode value of the one-char string `obj`, you should use `ord(obj)` instead of `chr(obj)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the integer unicode value of the one-char string `obj`, you should use `ord(obj)` instead of `chr(obj)`.

The difference between `b'test'` and `'test'` is the data type. The first one is a bytes object, where each character in the `b''` literal corresponds to exactly one byte in the bytes object (thus only ASCII characters are allowed in the literal). The second is a unicode string.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by Thomas Hilberts Comment, the right code is:

```
def encode(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        if len(obj) == 1 and ord(obj) < 128: 
            return obj
```

now it works.